# Theme logo and site name

Tags: theming

how can I put **logo** and **site name** in an unordered list? 
I am using a bootstrap subtheme !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you're going to want a custom template file (.tpl.php in D7, .html.twig in D8).

In Drupal 8, the logo and site name are contained within Bootstrap's block--system-branding-block.html.twig; in Drupal 7, they're set in Bootstrap's page.tpl.php. If you go into that file, you can change how those elements are rendered - just wrap them in the necessary  /

tags and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I am using drupal 7. I have tried to make modification to page.tpl.php, so it means I am on the right path, but, can I get more help on how exactly I can do that ? I am a begginer. Is this ok <header id="navbar" role="banner" class="<?php print $navbar_classes; ?>">
  <div class="<?php print $container_class; ?>">
 
    <div class="navbar-header">

**<ul class= "list inline">**

      <?php if ($logo): ?>
...
  <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!empty($site_name)): ?>
.....

Comment: Just make sure to wrap the whole thing in <ul> and each element (logo, sitename) in <li> and you should be good. It looks like your HTML should be good, but if you put it in a `code` block by editing your original answer, I can help a little better.

My only warning - if you write the code this way and have the <ul> outside your `<?php if ?>` statements, the <ul> will always print (even when you don't have a title / logo). If you'll always have a title / logo, that's fine. If not, wrap the full <ul> in another - <?php if ($logo) || (!empty($site_name): ?>

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! it worked ! thank you so much. Here is the modification I made. Thanks for pointing out about the position of ul

```
 `<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="<?php print $navbar_classes; ?>">
  <div class="<?php print $container_class; ?>">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <?php if (!empty($logo) || !emtpy($site_name)): ?>
      <ul class="list-inline"> 
        <?php if ($logo): ?>
       <li> <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-right" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
          <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
        </a></li>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($site_name)): ?>
        <li><a class="name navbar-brand pull-right" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></li>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($primary_nav) || !empty($secondary_nav) || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only"><?php print t('Toggle navigation'); ?></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <?php endif; ?>
            </ul> 
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>`
```